# Stop a Service started with an HandlerThread

Tags: android, android-service

I created a service that run a task using a HandlerThread.
I simplified my code, for readability issues.

From an activity by clicking a button I start the service that prints the numbers from 1 to 10. From the same activity I would have a chance to stop the service by pressing the stop button. If I click the stop button the  OnDestroy method of service is called but my task continues to run until the numbers from 1 to 10 are printed.

Thanks in advance for the responses.

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {

    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private LocalBroadcastManager mLocalBroadcastManager;
    private HandlerThread thread;

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }

            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);

        mLocalBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("message", intent.getIntExtra("message", 0));
        msg.setData(b);

        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "DESTROY");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to stop the HandlerThread by either calling "quit()" or "quitSafely()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the service onDestroy, interrupt the running thread with:

```
thread.interrupt();
thread.quit();
```

Then when your sleep is interrupted, break out of the loop so the thread can terminate by returning from the handleMessage method.

EDIT: I will add that it's kind of "bad form" to sleep during bits of work executed on a HandlerThread.  If you need to schedule work to occur periodically, you can schedule those by posting delayed messages to a Handler/HandlerThread.  Then you can just `quit` the thread without having to interrupt it.

Comment: thanks @doug-stevenson. The code that I put was just to slow my printing process and see if it worked or not when clicked the stop button from my activity.

Comment: Then quit should still do the trick if you don't need to interrupt a blocking method.

Comment: in my service I download a big file .zip. I tried to use only `thread.quit()` but the task run until the end. If add `thread.quit()` and `thread.interrupt()` it works perfectely. But if I have multiple instances of the same service how do I stop a downlaod process rather than another?

Comment: This sounds like a whole new question to me.